# VBA How do I run only 1 of 3 subs?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have 3 textboxes for user input, user can input any one of the textboxes and the other 2 will fill. However, when the first sub runs, the second or third should not run, when the second runs first and third should not run, etc. I've shortened the codes to input fixed values as the actual codes require opening of multiple other files which is very lengthy.

With the current code, it only works without error messages popping out when you feel the last of the textbox (aka 3rd sub).

```vb
Private Sub tbA_AfterUpdate()
    'If user enters text, run this code
    If tbA Is Nothing Then
        tbA = ""
    Elseif tbA.TextLength > 0 Then
        tbB = "NA"
        tbC = "NA"
    End If
End Sub

'the problem starts here if user inputs into tbA, this code still runs
'prompting an error message
Private Sub tbB_AfterUpdate()
    'If user enters text, run this code
    If tbB Is Nothing Then
        tbB = ""
    Elseif tbB.TextLength > 0 Then
        tbA = "NA"
        tbC = "NA"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tbC_AfterUpdate()
    'If user enters text, run this code
    If tbC Is Nothing Then
        tbC = ""
    Elseif tbC.TextLength > 0 Then
        tbA = "NA"
        tbB = "NA"
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First fix up your missing End If

Comment: @david thank you for pointing out! Missed out while shortening!

Comment: How/ where are they being called from?

Comment: Not sure how tbA, tbB or tbC could be `Nothing`...

Comment: Did you post your exact code? Because on my computer setting the TextBox values by code doesn't trigger the AfterUpdate event

Comment: @Dean from the textbox that user inputs

Comment: @VincentG user only has to key in 1 textbox and the others would populate with values, this is an summary of what it does, which I extracted values for the other 2 textbox with other codes

Comment: You need to introduce a `Public` `Boolean` that you can use to alternate as a "switch" for the procedures to run. ie. when the switch is off (`False`), then all subs have the potential to run. As soon as a user inputs a value that sub runs and the switch is turned on or `True`. This way you can manage the execution across them.

Comment: [AfterUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/afterupdate-event) should not be triggered from code modifications (While Change is), so it suggest you have other code somewhere that interact with your textboxes.

Comment: @Dean sory, I'm still pretty new to this, how do I go about doing this? Do you have a link that could possibly elaborate?

Comment: @VincentG I've attempted with the `Change` and as soon as i key in the letter, everything runs which is not what i want, thus its an `AfterUpdate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either a `Public` `Boolean` to help with managing the execution of your routines or another method would be to store a value in a cell and use that as reference as a controller. The below code is not tested, but should give you the principle:

Declare the boolean as a global variable. You do this by inserting the below line at the TOP of a normal module in your project.

```vb
Public bFlag As Boolean
```

Then the below goes into your relevant modules. Note the use of the boolean to simply switch on and off.

```vb
Private Sub tbA_AfterUpdate()
    If bFlag = False Then
    'If user enters text, run this code
    If tbA Is Nothing Then
        tbA = ""
    ElseIf tbA.TextLength > 0 Then
        tbB = "NA"
        tbC = "NA"
    End If
    'set bool to true
    bFlag = True
    End If
End Sub

'the problem starts here if user inputs into tbA, this code still runs
'prompting an error message
Private Sub tbB_AfterUpdate()
    If bFlag = False Then
    'If user enters text, run this code
    If tbB Is Nothing Then
        tbB = ""
    ElseIf tbB.TextLength > 0 Then
        tbA = "NA"
        tbC = "NA"
    End If
    'set bool to true
    bFlag = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tbC_AfterUpdate()
    If bFlag = False Then
    'If user enters text, run this code
    If tbC Is Nothing Then
        tbC = ""
    ElseIf tbC.TextLength > 0 Then
        tbA = "NA"
        tbB = "NA"
    End If
    'set bool to true
    bFlag = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this, just use the flag - type boolean to check, if your value was updated manually or by code

```
 Private Sub tbA_AfterUpdate()
    'If user enters text, run this code
     If tbA Is Nothing Then
        tbA = ""
     Elseif tbA.TextLength > 0 Then
        tbB = "NA"
        tbC = "NA"
        tbBupdatedByCode = True
        tbCupdatedByCode = True
     End If
End Sub

 'the problem starts here if user inputs into tbA, this code still runs
 'prompting an error message
 Private Sub tbB_AfterUpdate()

    If tbBupdatedByCode = False
     'If user enters text, run this code
      If tbB Is Nothing Then
      tbB = ""
    Elseif tbB.TextLength > 0 Then
      tbA = "NA"
      tbC = "NA"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the boolean part works, this makes it run, but when I input a value in tbB, it runs the update of tbB and then A > B > C. So it cycles through all 3.

Comment: yes of course it cycles through all 3 subs.. but as it is updated by code, code in all 3 subs will not run.. because condition